# How to use `prefer-dist` command line composer option inside the composer.json file, so that it is not a one time per command but a lasting setting?

Tags: php, composer-php

How to use a `prefer-dist` command line composer option inside the composer.json file, so that it is not a one time per command setting but a lasting setting inside a composer.json file throughout the project libraries installations?

Reference:
https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6798

Answer (score 3):

As picked up from the documentation, composer exactly states, literal wording at the time being (should be listed the option preferred-install with listed values):

"preferred-install# Defaults to auto and can be any of source, dist or auto. This option allows you to set the install method Composer will prefer to use. Can optionally be a hash of patterns for more granular install preferences."

```
{
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "my-organization/stable-package": "dist",
            "my-organization/*": "source",
            "partner-organization/*": "auto",
            "*": "dist"
        }
    }
}
```

Reference link:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#preferred-install